# Minimal and Maximal Elements in a Relationship With Multiple Different Conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am  currently struggling to understand how to determine parts b, c  and d of this problem. I think I understand the definition of minimal and maximal elements, but what about in this case with multiple conditions? I.E. for this set $X = \{0,1\}$, and condition (i), $0$ satisfies being a partial order of all other elements, but for condition (ii) a,b,c and d could all be $0$, and so for condition (ii) wouldn't $0$ not be a partial order of itself? What am I missing or misunderstanding? Thanks in advance to those who answer!

[image: math_problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the setup of the problem.

The set $A$ consists of the ordered pairs $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$.

The partial order relates two such pairs. For example, $(0,0) \mathscr{R} (1,0)$ because $a=0$ and $c=1$ and $a<c$.

Comment: Ah, so then for minimal and maximal elements are we actually comparing SETS -- that is, I suppose in this case the maximal element would be (1, 1)?

Comment: @SimonWard I would call $(a,b)$ a "tuple" or "ordered pair" rather than "set" (sets do not consider the ordering of its elements, i.e. $\{a,b\} = \{b,a\}$). But yes $(1,1)$ is a maximal element.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! So then (0, 0) would be the minimal element as well?